# why adding a form of authentication is complicated?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am new to MVC and razor, and i am trying to create a website using asp.net mvc 4 framework, Now i created a lot of tricks, and everything looks fine, but when i want to add a user authentication form, i found a lot of problems.

Login form :
[image]

first, i begin by creating a new mvc 4 project, and i chose internet application, then I tried to understand Account controller, Account Model, InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute, 9views !!, but i can't, why these things are more complicated ? why with php we can easily create login form?

can someone guiding me, or giving me links to understand step by step how can i set up my login form ??

Comment: ASP.NET Identity could be pretty easy if you know how it works. Read this first and get some overall idea about it: http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: I'd suggest not to work with the membership provider for a while, just create your login with your own code. The membership provider is quite hard to understand and it can really be a pain for a beginner. Just make sure you secure your login enough. Use sql parameters, antiforgerytoken etc.

Comment: Jamie - rolling your own authentication provider is a really bad idea unless you know exactly what you are doing. *Getting security right is hard* and poor security on websites is a currently a major problem for the industry, with hundreds of thousands of user credentials being lifted from websites with poorly implemented user management.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using MVC 4 as opposed to MVC 5 and the new ASP.NET Identity user management? Although relatively new, you might find this easier to work with - especially following the samples at https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/. Microsoft have said this is the membership framework that is here to stay and it would be worth looking into it to avoid the pain of migrating further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you are just having difficulty understanding the concept of MVC4, so may I recommend that instead of jumping in the deep end and trying to understand the membership provider you get started on this awesome tutorial on MVC4 via Microsoft:

[ASP.NET MVC4 Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)

This will explain to you the basics of MVC, help you get started on a basic implementation of an MVC site, introduce you to the concept, and eventually get on to the membership provider.It is definitely worth doing, it won't take too long and after you will feel enlightened.

When you are finished I recommend checking out this overview:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview

I hope this helps.